# Show that $\bar{a}_{n}(\bar{x})^n+···+\bar{a}_{1}\bar{x}+\bar{a}_{0}=0_{F[x]/I}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $F$ be a field, $f(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial in $F[x]$ and $I =(f(x))$. Let $f(x)= a_nx^n+···+a_1x+a_0, a_i \in F$ for $i=0,...,n$. And, $\bar{x} = x + I ∈ F[x]/I$  and $\bar{a_i} = a_i + I \in F[x]/I, \forall a_i \in F \subseteq F[x].$

Show that $\bar{a}_{n}(\bar{x})^n+...+\bar{a}_{1}\bar{x}+\bar{a}_{0}=0_{F[x]/I}$.

Here, all I know is that $I$ is a maximal ideal and $F[x]/I$ is a field. But, I don't know how to prove $\bar{a}_{n}(\bar{x})^n+...+\bar{a}_{1}\bar{x}+\bar{a}_{0}=0_{F[x]/I}$. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The ring hom $\rm\:g\mapsto \bar g = g + \left<f\right> \:$  preserves $\rm\:\color{#a0f}{sums}\,\ \&\,\ \color{#0a0}{products}\:$ so it preserves $\rm\color{#c00}{polynomials}$ by induction, since polynomials are compositions of sums and products. $ $ More explicitly

$$ \begin{eqnarray}
\rm 0\, =\ \overline{\color{#c00}{f(x)}}\:
&=&\rm\ \  \overline{a_n x^n +\,\cdots + a_1 x + a_0}\\
&=&\rm\,\ \overline{a_n x^n}\, +\,\cdots + \overline{a_1 x} + \overline a_0\quad by\ \ \ \color{#a0f}{\overline{g+h}\ =\, \overline g + \overline h}\ \ \ \,\forall\ g,h \in F[x]\\
&=&\rm\,\  \overline a_n\,  \overline x^n+\,\cdots + \overline a_1\overline x + \overline a_0\quad by\ \ \ \color{#0a0}{\overline{g\, *\, h}\, =\, \overline g\, *\, \overline h}\ \ \ \forall\ g,h\in F[x]  \\
&=&\rm\  \bar{\color{#c00}f}(\overline{\color{#c00}x})\\
\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: maybe this is a very trivial question, but how is $\overline{f(x)} = 0$?

Comment: I meant to say why is $\overline{f(x)} = 0$?

Comment: @Jellyfish $\ f\in I \,\Rightarrow\, \bar f = f+I = 0+I = \bar 0,\,$ i.e. $\, f\in I\,\Rightarrow\, f\equiv 0\pmod I\ \ $

Comment: oops! missed that logic. Thanks.