# Field Extension and Minimal polynomial

Tags: finite-fields, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

Below is example of extending Field $F$ to include root of a irreducible polynomial. After extending Field $F$ to ploynomial Field $F[t]$ , we take polynomial $p=t^{3}+t+1$ and declare it is equal to zero in that polynomial ring. It makes

$t^{3}+t+1=0$  so it leaves

$t^{3}+t^{2}+t+1=t^{2}$

After all the subsequent subsitution it will leave only the first,second and third row.
My question is

How the other elements of row 3 are eleminated. I only understand the above two subsitution. How will the further subsitution works?

Roots of this polynomial is $t$, how?

Is the polynomial is minimal polynomial? 
[image: example]

Comment: mod $\,t^3+t+1\!:\,\ t^3+t+1\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, t^3\equiv -t-1\equiv t+1\,$ so you can use that as a rewrite rule $\,t^3\to t+1\,$ to reduce all expts on $t$ to be $< 3.\ $ Equivalently, you can replace $\,f(t)\,$ by its remainder on division by $\,t^3+t+1,\,$ which has degree $< 3\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque thanks for guidance,above point is now clear to me. Can u please tell me why $t$ is root of given polynomial, why not other?

Comment: ${\rm mod}\ g\!:\,\ f\equiv 0\iff g\mid f.\ $ Of course $\,g\,$ cannot divide a lower degree polynomial (except 0).

Comment: As for the "root" viewpoint in quotient rings [see this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1243971/242)